# ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, permissions, users

My Users table crashed and I had to do a repair on it, now I'm getting the error:

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

No matter how I try to connect

> mysql -u root
>
> mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1
>
> mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root -p
>
> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Now the only way I can open the database is with

> mysqld  --skip-grant-tables

However if I gain access by this method I can't grant the original permissions back

```
grant all on *.* to root@localhost with grant option; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Is there a solution to escape this catch 22? Or am I destined to use --skip-grant-tables forever?

I really don't want to export and import 30GB worth of data into a new database.

Comment: No that would not  work,. try in another command window, now that mysql is running mysqlcheck –repair mysql user

Comment: @nbk I am using another window to run the commands. Repairing the user table is how I got into this mess. After I repaired the table, MySQL would start but I can't use root@localhost anymore.

I just tried running that again anyway...

(HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

No change.

Comment: That's why it is necessary to make an update befpre major changes. try also UPDATE user SET `authentication_string` = PASSWORD('myNewPassword') WHERE `User` = 'root';  and see if there is a user root. and you can change its password

Comment: I didn't make any changes, the database crashed. I always make backups before making changes. I had (another) look at the user table and while it had shown users earlier (after the repair) and I had even made modifications, it wasn't showing any rows anymore. I shut down MariaDB and replaced the user table files with those from a separate data folder I'd made earlier (thanks MyISAM for being simple) and all is working again now. Thanks for your help!